# Distinguishing two streets with the same name?

Tags: line, overpass-api, duplication

I am trying to get road data using the Overpass API. I want a user to be able to find a street using its name then retrieve the data for the nodes to draw a line on the map. This is all fine using:

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
(
  way["name"="<streetName>",i](51.388370, -2.421840, 51.410317, -2.361116);
);
(._;>;);
out body;
```

The problem is when a road has the same name as another in the bounding box. For example in the UK "High Street" is a common street name. I can't see any tags (even using verbose output) that give me more information about where the street is. Obviously there is the actual geographic node data but this isn't human-friendly.

Is there any way to work out any more information about a way (specifically a street/highway) to distinguish them to humans?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear about what a user is supposed to see. Maybe a list of search results, like on the osm.org search., or maybe some points on a map? Overall this sounds like you're looking for a geocoder, such as Nominatim. From Overpass API side, you could find all parts of a street with the same name, like in this demo: https://mmd-osm.github.io/complete_demo

Comment: Eventually I want to draw a line on the street, but first I want to give the user an autocomplete list of streets to choose from. The user will then select the name. I send this exact name back with a recursive call for the nodes to draw the lines. This could then actually include different streets.
I've "solved" finding all parts of the same street by searching for the exact name and taking all the ways, but this forces the issue of getting unrelated duplicates.
The demo you linked solves some of this by using the location that is clicked, reducing dramatically likelihood of a duplicate.

Comment: Note that streets may not be continuous. For example Jabłonkowska in Kraków (http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/Amy ) was split by new roads and now is in at least 4 parts. Do you want to count it as one street or four separate ones?

Comment: that should be one street if it is the same street, though I recognise it can be difficult to know that for sure.